# How to run a cron job on OSX for php using MAMP

Tags: php, macos, cron

I've been at this for hours and have tried everything with no luck.

I am basically trying to run this http://docs.phpservermonitor.org/en/latest/install.html#setting-up-a-cronjob

I'm using MAMP and my localhost is a custom folder under User/username/localhost/servercheck

What I've tried so far is.

crontab -e
added  `*/1 * * * * root /usr/bin/php /Users/clientsupport1/localhost/servercheck/cron/status.cron.php`

And when I type crontab -l to see if its loaded I see the following.

```
*/1 * * * * root /usr/bin/php /Users/clientsupport1/localhost/servercheck/cron/status.cron.php
```

But the script does not run. I even tried a simple script that writes to a file. Still nothing. For some reason the cron job doesn't execute. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: @JayBlanchard where does the errors for crontab get dumped? I can have a peak

Comment: Look in /var/log, but first look at the PHP log files.

Comment: @JayBlanchard do you want me to look in the system log?

Comment: I want you to look in the PHP error logs. CRON is not likely failing.

Comment: @JayBlanchard dont error go directly to `STDERR` when running from the CLI? Also the system should deliver failures to your user mail which you can take a look at in terminal by doing `mail` - though it should notify you if you have new messages when you open a terminal session.

Comment: It depends if logging was setup for the CLI (on most MAMP installs I've seen, it is) @prodigitalson

Comment: Hmmm its not on my default macports install or on my debian boxes. Thats why i asked :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call MAMP’s PHP executable, which will depend on on the version of PHP you’re running. For 7.2.1, the following below would be the proper path

```
*/1 * * * * /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/bin/php /Users/clientsupport1/localhost/servercheck/cron/status.cron.php
```