# Process PDF Generation and Send Email Asynchronously

Tags: php, asynchronous

I have a form which allows users to create up to 10 contest entries at one time. I use a web service to generate a PDF doc of their contest entry for each one which can take up to 5-6 seconds each. I would prefer NOT to have to wait up to a minute for the user to see the completed submission page, so I'd like to do the PDF/email part asynchronously.

I've looked here but each solution seems to require additional PHP enablements (e.g. fastcgi_finish_request() which needs php-fpm; spatie/async which requires pcntl & posix) which I don't see enabled on my customer's hosting site, and I can't ask them to change their configuration.

What would be the best way to queue up async tasks like this in PHP?

Comment: Store the task in a database. Fire off a php script using cron which reads the database and processes all jobs in there.

Comment: @ptrTon: great idea. Do you know if it’s possible to create a cron job on my MAMP PRO on Mac OS? That way I can test in my Dev environment

Comment: @RossW seems like you can according to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28202224/how-to-run-a-cron-job-on-osx-for-php-using-mamp)

Comment: Thanks heaps @PtrTon!